# Netty4 application as both client and a server

Tags: java, netty

I want to write a program in Netty4 that should act as a server to other clients and also it itself is a client to another server. How to do this in Netty4? So far all examples I have seen are either client or server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special difficulties here. You need to create a part that will act as a server (using `ServerBootstrap`), and a part that will act as a client (using `Bootstrap`).

If you need to establish a connection to another server while handling incoming connection from a client, you can place that logic into a `ChannelHandler` of the server's pipeline.

Netty provides two examples of this approach:

- [Hex dumping proxy](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy)
- [SOCKS proxy](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/socksproxy)